# Capturing bitmapData from a video display playing a h.264 (mp4) video

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I have a video file which I play in an Android air app. I'm trying to capture a frame using `bitmapData.Draw(video)`, but it works only for .flv video.

The videos are played locally - no internet or server.

Once I change the video to an .mp4, it plays it on stage, but has a blank bitmapData after the draw function is called. I doesn't say any error.

How can I capture a frame from the played .mp4 video?

Note - 
It's a Video component, not a `StageVideo`, since I know it's impossible with `StageVideo`.

The net stream initialization. I also added the `checkPolicyFile = true` - it didn't help.

```
my_nc.connect(null);
my_nc.client = this;

_ns = new NetStream(my_nc);
_ns.client = this;
_ns.useHardwareDecoder = true;
_ns.checkPolicyFile = true;
```

Comment: See [**this link**](http://gamespoweredby.com/blog/2014/11/netstream-playnull-bitmapdata-workaround/). It suggests how to draw the container of video pixels (a _graphicsData_ object).

Answer (score 4):

UPD:
It seems there isn't way to draw h.264 video in bitmap on android devices by ActionScript.
I tested this [demo](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/77217007/stackoverflow/h264draw_test/index.xhtml)([sources](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/77217007/stackoverflow/h264draw_test/videotest.as)) with [this](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/77217007/stackoverflow/h264draw_test/big_buck_bunny_trailer_480p_high.mp4) h.264 encoded video file (It's [origin](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/graphics/videoformatsupport/default.html)) in mp4 container in mobile FlashPlayer 11.1 and in AIR 3.5 application with the same code and both of them have failed. I've got the black rectangle in all render modes (direct, cpu and gpu).

The possible workaround can be to write the native extension making screenshot (I found [this](https://github.com/abhisek-mishra/ScreenShot) one, but it's reported can crash you app, but sources can be helpful) and crop the video by known rectangle. It's not a beautiful solution, but I don't see the other variants for now.

Comment: That's a totally different environment. I said my problem occurs with Air on Android, and this is an example of a swf in the web... yes, it captures the image for me too.. and I use the same code in my project. doesn't work. different environments. 
I think the main difference is that my file is played locally as well.
But I think that the main difference is that the file local as well in my project.
I also tried to use exactly the same .mp4 file in your example. doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, I see. I test this code on my android and got full black screen shot as well. I'll try to solve the problem tomorrow and than update the answer.

Comment: I updated my answer, but there isn't good news. It's interesting question and I'll continue attempts to find solution. I think that posting the bug in https://bugs.adobe.com/flex/ will also be the good idea.

Comment: Thanks for the effort mate. I might end up finding a really dirty solution.

Answer (score 0):

I came across something similar once.
have you tried placing the Video comp in an empty sprite and Drawing from that.
ie from the video's parent as opposed to directly.

Comment: now it gives me this :

`SecurityError: Error #2123: Security sandbox violation: BitmapData.draw: app:/Example.swf cannot access null. No policy files granted access.
 at flash.display::BitmapData/draw()`

And I already tried setting `_ns.checkPolicyFile = true;`

Again. this is a local .mp4 video file on Android.

Comment: sorry to ask a silly question, have you added the policy file? where, and what is in it?

Comment: check out this post http://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?5459-BitmapData-draw()-security-problem

Comment: all the threads that I found were about remote files. I don't have one.
So I create a policy.xml ? what should be in it ?

I'm gonna check your link and get back to you. thanks.

Comment: I'm constantly capturing while the video is playing.. it doesn't bring up the security issues, but it doesn't capture the image as well ! :\

Answer (score 0):

Try the concept shown at [**this link**](http://gamespoweredby.com/blog/2014/11/netstream-playnull-bitmapdata-workaround/).

It suggests how to draw the container of video pixels (a *graphicsData* object).

```
myBitmap.bitmapData = GraphicsBitmapFill(vidContainer.graphics.readGraphicsData()[0]).bitmapData;
```

Comment: The question is from 2013. Now you can easily do it with Adobe Air 24 & Starling's video texture.